# How do I define a prop type as a <div> in Flow?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm writing a React component using ES6 Classes, and one of my `props` can be either a `string` or a `<div>`.

How do I tell Flow that the `<div>` is acceptable?

Currently:

```
import React from 'react'

type Props = {
  title: string,
  content: string | // <- or a div
};

export class ThisComponent extends React.Component {
// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the global type `React$Element`

```
type Props = {
  title: string,
  content: string | React$Element<any>
};
```

AFAIK you can't restrict to only `div`s though

```
<ThisComponent title="mytitle" content={<div/>} /> // <= ok
<ThisComponent title="mytitle" content={<a/>} />   // <= ok as well
```

Comment: Here is a reference to the above-mentioned global type: https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/5a8ec2deb96d4f69d458d3961cd6d09b5a387216/lib/react.js#L121

Answer (score 0):

For future travellers, I think the Flow type for a `<div>` is `HTMLDivElement`.

For example, in your case above where you wanted either a string or div:

`type Props = {
  content: string | HTMLDivElement,
};`

Answer (score -2):

You should use `React.PropTypes.node`:

> Anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or an
>   array (or fragment) containing these types.

and then just in your component use it like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="myComponent">
      <h3>My super component</h3>
      <div className="content">
        {this.props.content}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

so after your component declaration:

```
ThisComponent.propTypes = {
  content: React.PropTypes.node,
  title: React.PropTypes.string,
};
```

Comment: thanks @Hardy. will `Flow` pick up `*.propTypes` in addition to `type Props =  {}` ? & will it merge/reconcile the two if both are present? eg, if some `props` are better validated in `type Props...` & some are more suited for `*.propTypes...`?